# How to just refresh 1 worksheet Excel

Tags: vba, excel

Just learning about advanced functions of excel/vb,

I'm having trouble finding just how to refresh 1 worksheet in a workbook. Currently I have

```
Sub my_onTime()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"), "refresh_FiveSeconds"
End Sub

Sub refresh_FiveSeconds()
    ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll
my_onTime
End Sub
```

This refreshes the workbook but cant find anything online which I just want to refresh worksheets seperately

Comment: So, you're trying to **refresh all external data ranges and PivotTable reports** in a single worksheet, correct?

Comment: @ashleedawg Correct, I've imported api data, into 3 seperate worksheets and I would like them to refresh at different times.

Comment: How did you import it?  Using "Get Data -> From Web"?  VBA? etc...  And so, there's only one imported table per worksheet, correct?  And you want it to re-query the data from the API -- ***every five seconds??***

Comment: @ashleedawg, correct, i used get data from web, then using now vba to update the worksheets automatically, although seperately e.g. one 5 seconds, next worksheet 30 seconds etc. Which is the part im having trouble with cause I cant find anything online which helps me

Comment: Have a global variable that you use to track which step you're on. So each time the 5 second event fires, it runs the refresh (on all relevant sheet's pivots) and increments the tracking variable. If that gets to 6, then 30 seconds have elapsed (6x5) and refresh the less regular sheet's pivots. Reset the tracker to 1 and the process starts again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to refresh all pivot tables in all worksheets, consider looping through the worksheets and working with the pivot tables:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws  As Worksheet
    Dim pt  As PivotTable

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        For Each pt In ws.PivotTables
            pt.RefreshDataSourceValues
            pt.RefreshTable
            pt.RepeatAllLabels
        Next pt
    Next ws

End Sub
```

If you want to refresh just specific worksheets, then you may introduce some type of a condition in the loop, e.g. `If ws.Name = "Sheet10WithPivots" Then`